# AWS codepipeline notification to slack not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, slack, amazon-sns, aws-codepipeline, aws-chatbot

I have configured notification rules for AWS CodePipeline to send notifications to Slack channels and these were working for the past 4 months and suddenly stopped working today. I tried to troubleshoot the issue using this [link](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/sns-aws-chatbot-message-troubleshooting/) but couldn't resolve it so far. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Note: Even AWS Chatbot is able to send test messages to channels and SNS Topic is also able to push notifications to the Email endpoint. I suspect that there is some issue with this [HTTPS endpoint](https://global.sns-api.chatbot.amazonaws.com).